# NGINX WWW.url.com says "Your connection is not private" but https://url.com is ok

Tags: nginx, ssl

Not sure why my redirect doesn't seem to work either...

I have a wildcard setup at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf` to direct all traffic away from www:

```
server {
   server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
   return 301 https://$1$request_uri ;
}
```

And in my sites-enabled folder also have this block:

```
server {
    if ($host = myhost.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting the message "Your connection is not private" if I go to https://www.url.com directly (no redirect happening)

Any ideas?

Comment: Those server blocks seem to implement redirection for `http` (port 80). Your question is about redirecting `https` (port 443).